# Call to SetLength returns nil

Tags: arrays, dynamic, freepascal

There is a procedure looking like this:

```
procedure blabla;
var buffer: array of byte;
begin
  Setlength(buffer, 10);
  Setlength(buffer, someinteger);
end
```

after both calls buffer is still **nil** <- this is my problem

I normally consider myself an experienced programmer and i use this fundamental method on various other occasions. This is driving me nuts.

Did anyone of you have similar issues in the past?
If so, what was the problem?

My code is somewhat spaghetti because i had changed any line that seemed suspicious, but here is the full code:

[full procedure](http://pastebin.com/mkEwkCAw)

@Edit:

i have this code in another part of the same project:

```
procedure interleaveVertexes;
var
  interleavedArray: array of TVec3Coord2; 
begin
  SetLength(interleavedArray, vertexcount);  
end;
```

and it works.. like it should

Comment: Have you confirmed that `someinteger` is *really* non-zero?

Comment: yeah, even changed the type to an unsigned.
but, even with the constant '10' it doesn't seem to work..
i am sooooo confused

Comment: with debugging i find the integer actually is 5052
also, turned optimizations on and off

Comment: Also, there is no segmenation fault when accessing memory from other routines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using gdb and the lazarus ide to debug and apparently..

Both of them dont like variables called 'buffer' or 'Data'.
I understand the lazarus ide internally is using gdb anyway.

Even a variable is just named 'h' wouldn't let itself be inspected properly.
i just renamed them to 'buffa' and 'howdy' and now it seems to be working.

Got there by doing old-fashioned print-debugging and storing the pointer of my array in a cardinal variable. There they were fine. (Apart from the actual content of the array)

annoingly funny